# Regex pattern to detect payload.* pattern

Tags: regex, scala

I want to validate all strings that have 'payload.*' i.e the string must start with 'payload' followed by a period (.) and followed by minimum 1 character.

example :-

```
Input1 :- payload.Hello     Output1 :-> Valid
Input2 :- Hipayload.Hello     Output1 :-> InValid
Input3 :- payload.H     Output1 :-> Valid
Input4 :- payload.     Output1 :-> InValid
```

Comment: `^payload\..` is something to start with

Comment: @snoram Thanks. Its working

Comment: and you haven't tried anything?

Comment: Please add it to your question. That way you will find the reason behind its failure. We don't call it embarrassment. We call it initial attempts to solve a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `x.matches(y)` (where `x` and `y` are both Strings) to match against a Regex pattern in Scala (or use "raw" Strings):

```
scala> val regex: String = "^payload\\..+"
regex: String = ^payload\..+

scala> val regexAltRaw: String = raw"^payload\..+"
regexAltRaw : String = ^payload\..+

scala> val regexAltTripleQuotes: String = """^payload\..+"""
regexAltTripleQuotes : String = ^payload\..+

scala> "".matches(regex)
res0: Boolean = false

scala> "payload.Hello".matches(regex)
res1: Boolean = true

scala> "Hipayload.Hello".matches(regex)
res2: Boolean = false

scala> "payload.H".matches(regex)
res3: Boolean = true

scala> "payload.".matches(regex)
res4: Boolean = false
```

To explain the pattern:

- `^payload` - starts with "payload"
- `\\.` - "." literally (without using "raw" Strings, Scala requires you to use double back-slashes to escape rather than single slashes like you would in normal Regex)
- `.+` - any character, one or more times

Comment: `val regex = ..` is a String pattern, it is not a `Regex`, which would require use of `.r`. You can build a pattern without double back-slashing using raw `String`s via `"""[pattern]"""` or `raw"[pattern]"`

Comment: `"^payload\\..+"` is a Regex Pattern within a String. I have added a type declaration to clarify. Good point about the `raw"..."` / `"""..."""`.

Comment: @ChaitanyaWaikar did this help you?

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid validation of input payload.. you can use foolowing regex:

```
^payload\.[^.]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

**Input Array:**

```
val ar = Array("payload.Hello","Hipayload.Hello","payload.H","payload.")
```

**Regex String:**

```
 val p = """^payload\..{1,}"""
```

**In Scala REPL:**

```
scala> val ar = Array("payload.Hello","Hipayload.Hello","payload.H","payload.")
ar: Array[String] = Array(payload.Hello, Hipayload.Hello, payload.H, payload.)

scala> val p = """^payload\..{1,}"""
p: String = ^payload\..{1,}
```

***Test:***

```
scala> ar.map(x=>if(x.matches(p))"Valid" else "InValid")
res3: Array[String] = Array(Valid, InValid, Valid, InValid)
```